# Does software-based OTFE cripple SSD performance without CPU AES?

Tags: ssd, encryption, aes

Sorry for the alphabet soup.

- I want to use software-based on-the-fly AES file encryption
- I will **not** use full disk encryption (only file and partition).
- This would be on an older **Core 2** system, so there is **no AES** instruction set.

Will this render any SSD performance gains moot?

**Edit:** I know not to use an SSD that utilizes encryption as a wear-leveling mechanism (ie.: not a Sandforce controller)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I gave up researching, so I just bit the bullet and bought one anyway.  Initial tests show minimal to no performance loss in a basic OS bootup test (Win7 x86), so I'm satisfied to say the answer to this question:

> Will an SSD's performance gains be lost on an AES-encrypted system that has a CPU with **no** AES instruction set, such as an Intel Core 2?

...is **No.  The performance is roughly equal, possibly negligibly less.**

The bootup process was maybe 3-5 seconds slower after encrypting.